# Failed to download repository information Check your Internet connection. 12.04

Tags: updates

I have an internet connection.  I tried to change the download server, but it didn't work. I have the following error message.

```
W:Failed to fetch gzip:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise_main_source_Sources  Hash Sum mismatch
, W:Failed to fetch gzip:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise_universe_source_Sources  Hash Sum mismatch
, W:Failed to fetch gzip:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise_main_binary-i386_Packages  Hash Sum mismatch
, W:Failed to fetch gzip:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise_universe_binary-i386_Packages  Hash Sum mismatch
, W:Failed to fetch gzip:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise-security_main_source_Sources  Hash Sum mismatch
, W:Failed to fetch gzip:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise-security_universe_source_Sources  Hash Sum mismatch
, W:Failed to fetch gzip:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise-security_main_binary-i386_Packages  Hash Sum mismatch
, W:Failed to fetch gzip:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise-security_universe_binary-i386_Packages  Hash Sum mismatch
, W:Failed to fetch gzip:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise-updates_main_source_Sources  Hash Sum mismatch
, W:Failed to fetch gzip:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise-updates_universe_source_Sources  Hash Sum mismatch
, W:Failed to fetch gzip:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise-updates_main_binary-i386_Packages  Hash Sum mismatch
, W:Failed to fetch gzip:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise-updates_universe_binary-i386_Packages  Hash Sum mismatch
, W:Failed to fetch gzip:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise_main_i18n_Translation-en  Encountered a section with no Package: header
, W:Failed to fetch gzip:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise_universe_i18n_Translation-en  Encountered a section with no Package: header
, W:Failed to fetch gzip:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise-security_main_i18n_Translation-en  Encountered a section with no Package: header
, W:Failed to fetch gzip:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise-security_universe_i18n_Translation-en  Encountered a section with no Package: header
, W:Failed to fetch gzip:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise-updates_main_i18n_Translation-en  Encountered a section with no Package: header
, W:Failed to fetch gzip:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise-updates_universe_i18n_Translation-en  Encountered a section with no Package: header
, E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: How are you connecting to the internet? is your connection wired or wireless? Can you give us anymore information such as which other download server you tried and why it didn't work? Please help us help you! Thank you!

Comment: Dear Elder Geek. Thank you for your help. I have wireless connection. I tried to download also from: ubuntu.mirrors.crysys.hu, ubuntu.sth.sze.hu, ftp.astral.ro, ubuntu.mirrors.linux.ro. I also tried the main server, but the error was still same, that what I wrote before.

Comment: Hash sum mismatch seems to indicate that what you are receiving is not what was sent. Based on the information available I would assume you have some interference problem or a malfunctioning wireless adaptor. The only other possibility is that all these servers in Hungary and Romania are having issues. I find the latter possibility doubtful in the extreme, and the former highly likely.

Answer (score 0):

Options:

1) Reorient the wireless adaptor antenna. If it's USB try using a USB extension cable and placing it higher.

2) Try connecting via wire (Ethernet cable) if possible

If #1 solves the problem it was caused by RF interference.

If #2 solves the problem it could still be either RF interference or a malfunctioning wireless adaptor.